# lookup gives error as from is missing inspite of correct query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup, mern

For [this](https://pastecode.io/s/h00njo52) Model in mongo using mongoose, and query as following : gets error **MongoServerError: missing 'from' option to $lookup stage specification: { localField: "vendor", foreignField: "_id", as: "vendors" }**

```
const items = await VendorItem.aggregate([
            {$lookup : { from: Vendor, localField: 'vendor', foreignField: "_id", as: "vendors"}},
            {$group: {categories: '$category'}}
        ]);
```

Comment: Can you check by replacing Vendor with 'vendors' for from property? Instead of giving the Vendor model name give it as a collection name.

Comment: @Arun it worked tysm!